# Would I have virtualization issues with the new Ivy Bridge Core i3-3225?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vt-d

The new processor does not support VT-d technology but I'm not sure if that would remove the ability to create a shared folder between the host(Ubuntu) and guest(Windows7). What effects would the absence of VT-d support cause in personal virtualization(virtualbox )?

I use Photoshop in the guest OS everyday but not very often. I know my setup is silly but I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a shared folder.

VT-d enables (with the right chipset, supporting IOMMU) PCI Passthrough, which can be used to run VMs with "dedicated" PCI hardware such as graphics cards, network cards, RAID cards and TV tuners.

From the uses you mention, this lack is unlikely to cause any issues.

Overall, for your usage, the answer is "No, you won't have issues with that processor".

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned network cards, would that affect internet connection in the guest OS? Not sure what you meant but I won't be using dedicated network cards just the in-built ethernet port.

Comment: Oh sorry, I realized it wouldn't. Thanks again!